# Calculate largest multiplier for large numbers in python

Tags: python, largenumber

I have three variables `a`, `b` and `c`. I want to find out the largest value for `b` where `a*b` is not greater than `c`. I want to make sure that after doing this:

```
c -= a*b
```

`c` is not negative. Note that I don't want to set the value of `c` by `c = max(0,c-a*b)`. I want to make sure that `b` is not big enough to make `c` negative.

I am doing this for now:

```
if a*b > c:
      b = c // a
```

but for very large numbers, I still get negative value in `c`. what should I do?

To reproduce the error here are some sample numbers:

a = 5.195497498518083

b = 1.0813434626413702e+16

c = 5.614533816817397e+16

I have tried the solution in the linked question but it does not solve the problem. I tried this:

```
Fraction(str(c)) // Fracktion(str(a))
```

Comment: Can you try casting to long?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting.  With your data, `a*b` certainly is greater than `c`.  What do you want it to do?  And why would you use integer division when you have floating point numbers?

Comment: I think he wants to find the largest `b` such that `a*b` is not greater than `c`.

Comment: yes, so since it is gerate than c I want to set b to a value so that a*b will not be greater than c. `c // a` should work for small numbers but not large numbers.

Comment: So, `b = c / a * 0.999`?

Comment: I have tried `Fraction(str(s)) // Fraction(str(b))` but it does not solve the problem

Comment: @rioV8 The original question was closed even though it was updated with the details that was requested. So no option except for asking new question.

Comment: @AUser Use `decimal.Decimal` instead. Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU1LDoIwFNz3FLMDtAKPV0proisvUipEEgsNYePpEQKzmm8m/pbPNLKJ87r28xTw7vwQ3BdDiNO84HVI4fBAUudka2UbZU1NpjSciHb3KS8NsWKlK62Im7LqrqQT4Y@RJlUzG9KGGrbNkTmJVsLLrRJcTM8fifQMskwMPRwuaPGEvwts2N88igJOxHkYl7TNTuJxO8rZuv4B "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: Question is still confusing. Is `b` given? I don't think so. Also better call it `x` or something. Also, why `x = c / a` is not a solution for floats or `x = c // a` a solution for integers?

Comment: `c/a` is not a solution because it is possible that `c/a*a>c` due to floating point errors.